# Cannot run PHP function when submit form. PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html, function

Hello I have the following 'edit' icon, and when I click over it, its open (something like lightbox) new window (iframe) inside the same page (without refreshing and etc.). In the newly opened iframe I have a form with 1 input. I would like when I click submit, to use the function (in the same .php file), to check if the value (which can be only numbers) is more than 299 to redirect to google.com, else to redirect to yahoo.com. (this sites are just examples.)
Here is my 'edit' icon code:

```
<div id="login-holder"><a href="#skinid"><img src="icons/edit.png" width="12px" height="12px" /></a></div>
```

Here is my #skinid div in the bottom of the script:

```
<div class="hidden">
<mark id="message"></mark>
  <div id="skinid">
  <section class="container">
    <div class="form2">
                        <form action="" method="POST">
                            <!--<fieldset class="textarea-field">
                                <textarea title="Message">Message</textarea>
                            </fieldset>-->
<br>
                            <fieldset>
                                <span class="ico user-ico"></span>
                                <input name="skinid" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" class="field" value="Enter new Skin ID. (-200$)" title="Enter new Skin ID. (-200$)" />
                            </fieldset>
                            <center><input type="submit" class="submit btn blue-btn" value="Update" /></center>
                        </form>
                    </div></section>
  </div></div>
```

I have tried with adding:

```
    if (isset($_POST['skinid'])) {
        if($_POST['skinid'] > 299) {header("Location:http://google.com");}
else {header("Location:http://yahoo.com");}
        return;
    }
```

above the form and it didn't work.

Comment: Yes and where is the problem to go about this?

Comment: I've updated my post with what I've tried.

Comment: @user215584 `it didn't work` != `this is the result it gave which is incorrect`

Comment: Obviously you are not here, willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you placed the PHP code right above the HTML form code, i.e. after some actual output has been sent. As the PHP manual states, the `header("Location:...")` should be called **before** any output has been sent.

Quoting the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

So, placing the PHP code before any HTML output has been sent (e.g. at the top of the file) should work. 
If not, then more detailed information will be necessary (as other commentors have already pointed out).